# won't call Game Center Cancel Match

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, game-center

i have this code to go to my ViewController if user press Cancel button when Game Center View appear.

```
- (void)matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled:
(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [Mytimer invalidate];

    ViewController *Vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:Vc animated:YES];


}
```

Where's my mistake? If i press Cancel, matchmakerViewController disappear, but won;t go to "Vc". Help please. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you instantiate a new VC? The practice is to present GC VC OVER your existing VC. And then the GC VC disappeared you just return to your VC. No need to instantiate it. It is like: assume your main and first displayed VC is called MainMenuVC. So you presenting the GCVC over your MainMenuVC and MainMenuVC stills on background while GCVC tkes control. If user presses Cancel in GCVC your code fires:

```
- (void)matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled:
(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [Mytimer invalidate];
}
```

Now you are returned back to your MainMenuVC. If you need to do something here like present another VC - you are free 2do it in MainMenuVC.